concatenate column values but must be unique
I have csv file, which has data,
Server,Department
testserver,Fin Tech
testserver,Fin Tech
testserver,Fin Tech
testserver,Fin Tech 
testserver,Fin Tech 
testserver,Fin Tech 
testserver,HR
testserver,Fin Tech 
testserver,Fin Tech 
testserver,Fin Tech 
testserver,Fin Tech 
testserver,Fin Tech 
testserver,HR
testserver,Fin Tech 
testserver,Fin Tech 

I need to keep all values in single field by concatenating them, but it should be unique.
eg: Fin Tech/HR
but I am getting result as Fin Tech/Fin Tech/Fin Tech/Fin Tech/Fin Tech/Fin Tech/HR/Fin Tech/Fin Tech/Fin Tech/Fin Tech/Fin Tech/HR/Fin Tech/Fin Tech
if [ -n "$current_Department" ] || [[ "$current_Department" == *"Department"* ]]; then
    bs_name="$current_Department/$Department"
fi


Did you mean to have extra whitespace at the end of some records? I recommend cleaning your input file, or if that's not in your data, then lets edit this post to remove it.

I noticed some of the lines in your file has end-of-line spaces. That could be messing up your uniqueness checks.

Using any awk:
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==1 { print; next }
    !seen[$1,$2]++ {
        depts[$1] = depts[$1] seps[$1] $2
        seps[$1] = "/"
    }
    END {
        for (srvr in depts) {
            print srvr, depts[srvr]
        }
    }
' file
Server,Department
testserver,Fin Tech/HR


The issue might be that the == operator in the [[ ]] test is doing pattern matching, not substring matching. If you want to check if current_Department contains Department, you should use the =~ operator instead.
Here is an example:
departments=""
lineNumber=0
# Header Line
while IFS=',' read -r server department; do
    # Skip the header
    if (( lineNumber == 0 )); then
        lineNumber=1
        continue
    fi
    # Trim whitespace (example has entries with space in the end)
    department=$(echo "$department" | xargs)
    # Check if the department is already in the list
    if [[ ! $departments =~ /$department/ ]]; then
        departments+="/$department/"
    fi
done < input.csv

# Remove the extra slashes
echo ${departments:1:-1} | tr -s '/'


Regularly I'm facing issues with doubled entries, I have the tendency of sorting them and getting the unique values, as follows:
... | sort | uniq

, where ... stands for any command, resulting in a list of entries, like cat, grep, awk ... '{print $n}', ...
(I have no answer for the header line, except tail -n $(($(wc -l file1.txt | awk '{print $1}') - 1)) file1.txt).
The latter stands for:

Calculate the number of lines in your file.
Subtract 1 of that number ($((calculation)) performs a calculation).
Use tail -n for getting that number of lines of your file.


sort | uniq = sort -u and tail -n $(($(wc -l file1.txt | awk '{print $1}') - 1)) file1.txt). = tail -n +2.

To do what you're suggesting would be ... | { IFS= read -r line && printf '%s\n' "$line"; sort -u; }. The prints the first input line as-is then pipes the rest to sort -u.

You say
if [ -n "$current_Department" ] || [[ "$current_Department" == *"Department"* ]]; then
    bs_name="$current_Department/$Department"
fi

but you don't say if or how $current_Department is set (if ever).
If you are just adding when the value changes, that won't work unless your input is sorted (which will likely displace your header).
Assuming you didn't mean for there to be extra whitespace at the end of some-but-not-all of your data records, here's an all bash implementation that basically reproduces the general logic of Ed's awk solution, in case you are more comfortable with bash than awk.
#!/bin/bash
declare -A unique_vals=() stacked=()
{ read -r hdr; echo "$hdr"
  while IFS=, read -ra col
  do k="${col[0]},${col[1]}"
     [[ -n "${unique_vals[$k]}" ]] && continue
     unique_vals["$k"]=1
     stacked["${col[0]}"]+="${col[1]}/"
  done
} < "$1"
for k in "${!stacked[@]}"; do printf "%s,%s\n" "$k" "${stacked[$k]%/}"; done

(The awk will be more efficient and noticeably faster on larger datasets.)
In use:
$: ./stack tst.csv
Server,Department
testserver,Fin Tech/HR

